# Added command(s) to .bashrc, how to apply to users retroactively?

Tags: bash, rhel, bashrc

I have a rhel 7 server that users will be connecting to, and I created ALL the users/groups then realize I needed to add a command to /etc/skel/.bashrc such that it executes upon login, but this doesn't seem to apply to the users I've already created. I created a new user and the commands execute upon logging in, just not for the existing users. Is there a way to update/force this upon existing users?

Comment: Are you concerned about overwriting the existing users' `~/.bashrc` files?

Comment: Interactive login shells will read /etc/profile.  Add the command there.

Comment: @JeffSchaller no they can be overwritten, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the command to the skeleton .bashrc.  Instead, put it in /etc/profile, which will be read upon startup for all interactive login (bash) shellsand non-interactive (bash) shells invoked with --login.

Even better (thanks, @glennjackman!) is to add a link in /etc/profile.d that ends with `.sh` with the necessary command.

Comment: or add a `.sh` file to /etc/profile.d

Comment: +2 to glenn jackman's suggestion. Down vote this response.  Don't ever edit /etc/profile.d, but make sure that /etc/profile.d sources things in /etc/profile.d . (which rhel 7 will do, although the mechanism is a bit kludgy IMO)